# CSS-only: Is it possible to center child elements with their pseudo element?

Tags: html, css

Let's say we have the following example code:

```html
<div class="sample-container">
  <p class="sample">a</p>
  <p class="sample">bbb</p>
  <p class="sample">cc</p>
</div>
```

and the css:

```css
.sample-container {
  display: grid;
  /* adapted grid-template-column for mobile view */
  grid-template-column: repeat(1, 1fr);
  justify-items: center;
}
.sample-container .sample {
  /* some styles */
}
.sample-container .sample::before {
  content: "symbol";
  /* some style for content */
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1.5rem;
  margin-left: -1rem;
}
```

While `justify-content` does center the child at this point, the `::before` pseudo element wouldn't be aligned. However, if I do:

```css
.sample-container {
  width: max-content;
  margin: auto;
}
.sample-container .sample {
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

It would only align the child without it's pseudo element to the center (as how `margin: auto` works). I also tried to make the parent of `.sample-container` `flex` and it still centers only the element itself without considering the pseudo elements.

I think it can be achieved with JS by getting the width of pseudo element and the child, then place them in the center, but I want it could be achieved with css tricks only (some people for whatever reason doesn't enable js, or whitelist only certain website to use js).

-----Update-----
To make it clear, here is a simple visual presentation:

```
+--------------------------+
|          O   a           |
|          O  bbb          |
|          O   cc          |
+--------------------------+
# I use O to mimic a symbol.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just delete `width: 1.5rem;` and `margin-left: -1rem;` from `.sample-container .sample::before`. Use `display:inline-flex` and position it with `position:relative; left:50%; transform: translateX(-50%);`

```css
 .sample-container {
     display: inline-flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     justify-content: center;
     position: relative;
     left: 50%;
     transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.sample-container .sample {
  /* some styles */
}
.sample-container .sample::before {
  content: "symbol";
  /* some style for content */
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="sample-container">
  <p class="sample">a</p>
  <p class="sample">bbb</p>
  <p class="sample">cc</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @jimmymcheung like that?

Comment: The `margin-left` was intend to create space between the symbol and the actual text. I make it this way because `.sample::before` will also applies to `li`

Comment: to create space use `margin-right` with positive value. Check update

Comment: It does seem to work, but when it is a list in-between paragraph, with `margin-right` the `symbol` would indent (instead of being in the margin of `ul`)

Comment: just set `padding-inline-start:0;` for ul

Comment: Thanks, it seems to move the `::before` to where the bullet of `li` belongs.

Answer (score 0):

This seems aligned and centered to me. And maybe just wrap everything inside a span or div that will be centered?

```css
.sample-container {
  display: grid;
  /* adapted grid-template-column for mobile view */
  grid-template-column: repeat(1, 1fr);
  justify-items: center;
}

.sample-container .sample {
  /* some styles */
}

.sample-container .sample::before {
  content: "symbol";
  /* some style for content */
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -1rem;
  color: red;
}

.all {
display:inline-block;
border: 1px solid blue;

}
```

```html
<div class="sample-container">
  <div class="all">
    <p class="sample">a</p>
    <p class="sample">bbb</p>
    <p class="sample">cc</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In this case yes, but the `symbol` pseudo element doesn't align to each other. I will update and visual example in the description.